Using W3CSS for a horizontal nav bar, have it so that when hovered over the text for a dropdown menu or background it changes the entire color
In my current implementation, it only changes the entire background color and the button of the when hovered over the text (where the button is). If not hovering over the button and instead the div, it only changes the background color of the <div>.
        <div style="width: 25%; font-family: 'Roboto Mono'; font-size: 28px;" class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hover-green w3-blue">
            <button style="width: 25%" class="w3-button w3-mobile w3-blue w3-hover-green w3-text-yellow">LORE</button>
            <div style="width:25%" class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block">
                <a href="GeneralLorePage.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-text-yellow w3-blue w3-hover-green">General Lore</a>
            </div>
        </div>

Desired behavior currently only works when hovering over the text/button/LORE, whereas it should work when hovering over the surrounding <div> as well.
Current Behavior
Desired Behavior
My go to thought would be use the . operator in order to refer the the descendant button within the div, but since I am using w3 css I am not sure how to refer to it due to the spaces between each w3 usage.

honestly, w3school is long outdated and even back then it had many bad tutorials. I would use an actual modern framework from a group with developers that actually know how to code themself such as Bootstrap.

I'll look into it, truth be told this is about the second method I've tried and ran into a problem with/difficulty.
